How can I make a google drive token refresh itself with a pyautogui function in python
I'm building a program that upload regurlarly videos on a google drive where I use them.
The thing is, I have to refresh often the tokens by manually clicking and I don't want that.
I built a function with Pyautogui that recognize the good email to click on, and press continue two times.
The thing is, when the window that ask me to refresh the token opens, it seems like the program freezes and stops working.
I thought about making it async but I did threading instead.
It strangely does not works.
Here are the program :
token_thread = threading.Thread(target=runtoken, args=(credentials,SCOPES))
clicker_thread = threading.Thread(target=TokenClicker, args=Drive)
clicker_thread.start()
token_thread.start()
token_thread.join()
clicker_thread.join()
print("Should be good")

Here is the runtoken function :
def runtoken(credentials, scopes):
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials, scopes)
    flow.run_local_server(port=0)

Here is the TokenClicker function :
def TokenClicker(Drive):
    time.sleep(2)
    if chaine == "Drive1":
        coordonees = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("TokenClicker/Email1.png")
    if chaine == "Chain":
        print("Drive2")
        coordonees = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("TokenClicker/Email2.png")
    
    pyautogui.moveTo(coordonees)
    
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    time.sleep(1)
    coordonees = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("TokenClicker/continue1.png")
    pyautogui.moveTo(coordonees)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    time.sleep(1)
    coordonees = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("TokenClicker/continue2.png")
    pyautogui.moveTo(coordonees)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w") ##Is supposed to be closing the windows

The function ClickToken(chain) is working fine I tested it successfully several times.
The function runtoken is successfully launching the webpage where I am supposed to click to choose the right email.
I am working through Parsec on a computer with a screen, a mouse, and a keyboard that works fine.

Can you complete the code process where you upload the file to the drive?
